# Characteristics of lupin and soy flours

Tags: baking, flour, vegan

I have to prepare something that will be eaten for breakfast or as a snack in the afternoon, using mainly lupin flour and (full fat) soy flour and without using eggs or milk/butter.

Since I'm not a chef, I would like to know which are the characteristics of these two flours so then I could choose the proper ingredients touse with the two flours.

Example of characteristics:

- how they mix with liquids ?
- does the high protein (~40g/100g) content influence the solubility ?
- what are their strength (W) ?

Comment: Hi Soundwave, your question touches an interesting topic. Sadly, I have to agree with logophobe here: Our site is optimized to deal with objective questions which potentially have a correct answer, and we cannot deal with questions where any number of answers can be equally correct, such as deciding whether to make crepes or cookies. So we just don't take that kind of question, even though they are legitimate questions for the person asking them.  But if you have something more specific in mind, you are free to come and ask again.

Comment: @rumtscho thanks for the replies and sorry for the off-topic I wrote my question really bad, in fact the main aspect I'm interested about is the behaviour of the two flours when mixed with a liquid, this is an objective question. I should have not put the focus on which kind of food to prepare (subjective) but on the properties of the flours (objective).

Comment: You can always edit your question to better match your intention and make it answerable, we are always happy when the posters do that! I think you are on a very good path there already. I am still struggling a bit what answers you need exactly - obviously, if you just ask "what happens when I mix the flours with liquid" and we answer "you get a mixture" that's not useful for anybody. What do you want about the properties of that mixture? What do you need it to be able to do, or what are you afraid that will happen? If you can focus on that, I see a good question there.

Comment: Sound wave, thank you very much for taking the time to improve your question! I have reopened and upvoted. I don't know the answer myself since I have never cooked with these flours, but I hope others will be able to give you some good info on them.

Comment: A really good edit @soundwave. Question, what do you mean by their strength?

Comment: @GdD it's a measure related to how well wheat flour binds. It has some theoretical underpinnings, but at the end it is simply determined empirically for each batch of flour. I haven't heard of it being defined for gluten free flours though.

Answer (score 1):

Some soya flour in a recipe helps to replace the eggs as soy has more fat than regular flour. I don’t know about lupin flour. You could use aquafaba to keep it moist etc, it replaces an egg in a cake recipe.

Try google for ingredients and quantities as we can’t give them here.